# Apply simplemembership to my database-first application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, simplemembership, ef-database-first

Hi I already read many articles about simple membership but I'm still confused about the concept. I'd like to apply simplemembership to my existing database UserProfile table. I have MVC4 Internet application. So I decided to modify (WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection). As I understand, It create a table if there is no co-responding table in the database. But I'm wondering what is up about AccountModels.cs class if I already have UserProfile in my edmx? AccountModels.cs already have several kinds of model class related to simplemembership. What is happening to this classes if I hook up UserProfile from database?